# Copy and rename files recursively using part of folder name for new name

Tags: command-line, rename, cp

I'm trying to recursively copy a folder of files containing `.csv` extensions and rename them while copying them into a single folder.

I'm close except for the file renaming which eludes me.

Can anyone assist?

```
find "/IMPORTS/EFHG2" -iname '*.csv*' -exec cp {} /temp/Template \;
```

As for the rename I'm looking for something that will give some indication of the parent folder from which the file came from.

- Original (`file1.csv`, `file2.csv`)
- Modified (`dir1.file1.csv`, `dir2.file1.csv`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having below structure:

```
├── destdir
└── srcdir
    ├── dir1
    │   └── with space.csv
    ├── dir2
    │   └── infile.csv
    └── dir3
        └── otherfile.Csv
```

running the command:

```
find "/path/to/srcdir" -type f -iname '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
    path="${1%/*}"; filename="${1##*/}";
    echo cp -nv "${1}" "/path/to/destdir/${path##*/}.${filename}" ' sh_cp {} \;
```

will produce output as following (running in dry mode):

```
cp -v /path/to/srcdir/dir2/infile.csv     /path/to/destdir/dir2.infile.csv
cp -v /path/to/srcdir/dir1/with space.csv /path/to/destdir/dir1.file with space.csv
cp -v /path/to/srcdir/dir3/otherfile.Csv  /path/to/destdir/dir3.otherfile.Csv
```

if we remove the `echo` in front of the `cp` command (which is used for dry-run) to get copy &rename affective, you will get below structure:

```
├── destdir
│   ├── dir1.with space.csv
│   ├── dir2.infile.csv
│   └── dir3.otherfile.Csv
└── srcdir
    ├── dir1
    │   └── with space.csv
    ├── dir2
    │   └── infile.csv
    └── dir3
        └── otherfile.Csv
```

note that if there was a same filename and same parent directory name say in sub-directories, it will overwrite with latest file found by the `find` command, that's why I used `-n` for the `cp` command to prevent that, so it will not copy that same file, be noted about that.

---

**Explanation:**

```
find "/path/to/srcdir" -type f -iname '*.csv' -exec sh -c '...' sh_cp {} \;
```

find files with `.csv` suffix (ignore-case) recursively and `-exec`ute the inline-`sh`-script for each `sh -c '...'` we name it `sh_cp`; the `{}` is the substitution of the *filepath* that find command finds it and we pass to our script and that is accessible on `$1` or `${1}` parameter.

- `${1%/*}`: cuts shortest-suffix from the `${1}` parameter (known [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)), as said above `${1}` is the *filepath* and with this we drop the *filename* + last `/` from the *filepath* and keep only *path* and store in the `path` variable.

  ```
  ${1}      --> /path/to/srcdir/dir2/infile.csv
  ${1%/*}   --> /path/to/srcdir/dir2
  ```
- `${1##*/}`: cuts longest-prefix from the `${1}` parameter; with this we remove *path* from the *filepath* and keep only *filename* and store in the `filename` variable.

  ```
  ${1}      --> /path/to/srcdir/dir2/infile.csv
  ${1##*/}  --> infile.csv
  ```

  and accordinlgy:

  ```
  path                    --> /path/to/srcdir/dir2
  ${path##*/}             --> dir2
  ${filename}             --> infile.csv
  ${path##*/}.${filename} --> dir2.infile.csv
  ```

---

tips:

```
xYz='to-test/path/to/srcdir/dir2/infile.csv'
${xYz%/*}   --> to-test/path/to/srcdir/dir2
${xYz%%/*}  --> to-test
${xYz#*/}   --> path/to/srcdir/dir2/infile.csv
${xYz#*/}   --> infile.csv
```

Comment: I've edited the question for an example of the output I'm looking for. Would you also mind helping me understand your solution?

Comment: Perfect! Also thank you for the great explanation...